# Error in creating Seam Custom EL function

Tags: jsf, seam, el, custom-component

I tried to create a custom el function in seam 2.2 by following http://seamframework.org/Documentation/CreatingCustomELFunctions

The taglib content is:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE facelet-taglib PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Facelet Taglib 1.0//EN" "facelet-taglib_1_0.dtd">
<facelet-taglib>
     <library-class>org.el.func.FnLibrary</library-class>
</facelet-taglib>
```

But while running, getting the following parsing error.

```
SEVERE [compiler] Error Loading Library: vfszip:/home/anand/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/stagebitz.ear/stagebitz.jar/META-INF/elfunctions.taglib.xml
java.io.IOException: Error parsing [vfszip:/home/anand/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/stagebitz.ear/stagebitz.jar/META-INF/elfunctions.taglib.xml]: 


Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXException: Error Handling [vfszip:/home/anand/jboss-5.1.0.GA/server/default/deploy/stagebitz.ear/stagebitz.jar/META-INF/elfunctions.taglib.xml@4,57] <library-class>

at com.sun.facelets.compiler.TagLibraryConfig$LibraryHandler.endElement(TagLibraryConfig.java:271)
```

Using JSF 1.2

In web.xml used following parameters.

```
 <context-param>
      <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_LIBRARIES</param-name>
      <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/elfunctions.taglib.xml
    </param-value>
   </context-param>
```

Comment: show the full stacktrace please

Comment: Your context parameter name is wrong, the one which you have shown is for JSF 2.x. The tutorial which you linked has however shown the right parameter name. That should only not have resulted in this exception. Perhaps your `FnLibrary` does not have a public constructor? Read further in the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Example to map isEmpty:

```
<!DOCTYPE facelet-taglib PUBLIC
        "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Facelet Taglib 1.0//EN"
        "http://java.sun.com/dtd/facelet-taglib_1_0.dtd">
<facelet-taglib>
     <namespace>yournamespace</namespace>
    <function>
        <function-name>functionname</function-name>
        <function-class>fullclanmae</function-class>
        <function-signature>java.lang.Boolean isEmpty(java.util.Set)</function-signature>
    </function>
</facelet-taglib>
```

Put it in your classpath, and it will work withouth anything in web.xml